# Update statement in Windows Forms application isn't working?

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my Windows Forms application I had placed textboxes in a groupbox and used following code to add 'N/A' to textbox if textbox is empty.

```
foreach (Control t in groupBox8.Controls)
                    {
                        if (t is TextBox)
                        {
                            if (t.Text == "")
                                t.Text = "N/A";
                            }
                    }
```

I am trying to update existing records using following code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE semester set paper1_name=@paper1_name, paper1_code=@paper1_code, paper1_marks=@paper1_marks, paper2_name=@paper2_name, paper2_code=@paper2_code, paper2_marks=@paper2_marks, paper3_name=@paper3_name, paper3_code=@paper3_code, paper3_marks=@paper3_marks, paper4_name=@paper4_name, paper4_code=@paper4_code, paper4_marks=@paper4_marks, paper5_name=@paper5_name, paper5_code=@paper5_code, paper5_marks=@paper5_marks, paper6_name=@paper6_name, paper6_code=@paper6_code, paper6_marks=@paper6_marks  where course=@course and semester=@semester");
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", "ABC");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", 1);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper1_name", textBox190.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper1_code", textBox188.Text);
                    if (textBox186.Text == "N/A")
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper1_marks", 0);
                    else
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper1_marks", textBox186.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper2_name", textBox189.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper2_code", textBox187.Text);
                    if (textBox185.Text == "N/A")
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper2_marks", 0);
                    else
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper2_marks", textBox185.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper3_name", textBox183.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper3_code", textBox181.Text);
                    if (textBox180.Text == "N/A")
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper3_marks", 0);
                    else
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper3_marks", textBox180.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper4_name", textBox177.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper4_code", textBox176.Text);
                    if (textBox175.Text == "N/A")
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper4_marks", 0);
                    else
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper4_marks", textBox175.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper5_name", textBox172.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper5_code", textBox171.Text);
                    if (textBox170.Text == "N/A")
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper5_marks", 0);
                    else
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper5_marks", textBox170.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper6_name", textBox179.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper6_code", textBox174.Text);
                    if (textBox169.Text == "N/A")
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper6_marks", 0);
                    else
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper6_marks", textBox169.Text);
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                        {
                            chk = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            label25.Text = "[Error: Cannot save the data]";
                            label25.Visible = true;
                            chk = 0;

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        cmd.Dispose();
                    }
```

But I am facing a problem in this. Everytime else part executes showing error message.

```
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                            {
                                chk = 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                label25.Text = "[Error: Cannot save the data]";
                                label25.Visible = true;
                                chk = 0;

                            }
```

And in database(semester table), also no record is updating. Please help. I am using sql server.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "ASP.NET Windows Forms" application. Seems like you got Windows Forms confused with Web Forms. I'll update the title...

Comment: You have a catch block. Are you getting an error?

Comment: @mason I am new to this so there might be mistake but I found this image http://aspxtutorial.com/image.axd?picture=2010%2F7%2Fcsharp%2F1.png please see this what I am creating.

Comment: Whats the exception??

Comment: @mason And I am not getting any exception in catch block.

Comment: @PareshJ No exception is coming. Only else part executes (please see  if..else code above).

Comment: @HarinderSingh: It will not return value greater than 0. It will always return -1. Hence you need to change your code.

Comment: @GrantWinney  I am trying to update existing records only.

Comment: Grant, Yes you are right. But using If Else Block in such a case is not orthodox way. Instead just if he could use cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() and On error He can show label text in catch block.

Comment: I also tried executing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` without if else. In this case no exception or error came. But also **no record** in database is updated.

Comment: @GrantWinney I had placed beak point on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() but I am not able get the generated SQL statement. I am new to it so please tell me how I can get that.

Comment: I found command text = "UPDATE semester set paper1_name=@paper1_name, paper1_code=@paper1_code, paper1_marks=@paper1_marks, paper2_name=@paper2_name, paper2_code=@paper2_code, paper2_marks=@paper2_marks, paper3_name=@paper3_name, paper3_code=@paper3_code, paper3_marks=@paper3_marks, paper4_name=@paper4_name, paper4_code=@paper4_code, paper4_marks=@paper4_marks, paper5_name=@paper5_name, paper5_code=@paper5_code, paper5_marks=@paper5_marks, paper6_name=@paper6_name, paper6_code=@paper6_code, paper6_marks=@paper6_marks  where course=@course and semester=@semester" .

Comment: And this query execute successfully after substituting appropriate parameter values.

Comment: After substituting appropriate parameter values query is "UPDATE       semester
set                paper1_name = 'aaaa', paper1_code = 'aaaa', paper1_marks = 444, paper2_name = 'aaaa', paper2_code = 'aaaa', paper2_marks = 34, paper3_name = 'aaaa',
                          paper3_code = 'aaaa', paper3_marks = 99, paper4_name = 'aaaa', paper4_code = 'aaaa', paper4_marks = 55, paper5_name = 'aaaa', paper5_code = 'aaaa', 
                         paper5_marks = 77, paper6_name = 'aaaa', paper6_code = 'aaaa', paper6_marks = 677
where        course = 'bbbb' and semester = 8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of you thanks for your efforts.
There was an error in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", "ABC");`.

Actually in my project I used global variable course in this statement (such as `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course);` ). I tried to simplify code while posting this question here and substituted value of variable course with value which I know. But I just forgot that I had changed value of variable course in another function. Thats why, where condition of sql query is not satisfying and also not giving any exception/error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this code
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", "ABC");`

use
`cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParameterName",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textboxName.text;`

In your code,  I can see that you're passing a value 0 (which is an integer) to some of the parameters but it accepts in your database a VarChar or Char.
P.S.
In "SqlDBType.VarChar" make sure the data type is the same with the one in the database.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply, but this also not worked. :(

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. There was an error in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", "ABC");`. Actually in my project I used global variable course in this statement (such as `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course);` ). But I just forgot that I had changed value of variable course in another function. Thats why where condition of sql query is not satisfying and also not giving any exception/error.

Comment: @HarinderSingh glad to hear that you've found the problem. Word of advice, for efficiency don't use AddWithValue it causes much of run-time, and for more info check this link http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/